# How to pass success message to another component via Axios Post method

Tags: reactjs, axios

I'm trying to pass a success message to my Dashboard component when I register a new user through the Axios POST method. I was able to pass my user data via a console log in the Dashboard component, however, I can't seem to properly set the state and pass a custom success message on successful registration. Any help will be much appreciated.

I've been able to console log the userData object but I've been unsuccessful in setting the state and passing a custom message.

***** This is my code to run the axios post to the API the set state is causing a 'Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'data' of undefined' within my separate Dashboard component.

```
    export const adminRegisterUser = (userData, history) => dispatch => {
      axios
       .post("/api/users/adminregister", userData)
       .then(res => {
          history.push("/dashboard")
          this.setState({ message: "Message sent successfully." });
       }) // Re-direct to dashboard on successful register and push a message confirming the registration.
        .catch(err =>
          dispatch({
          type: GET_ERRORS,
          payload: err.response.data
       })
      );
    };
```

***** This is the Dashboard component code to receive the state and display the success message.

```
     render() {
        return (
           <div style={{ width: "100%", backgroundColor: "#fff" }}className="valign-wrapper">
           <LoginNav />

           // Note that a console.log(userData) will output the userData here
           <div>{this.state.message}</div>
           <div className="row">
            <div className="col s6">
              <Chart />
            </div>
            <div className="col s6">
              <LineChart />
            </div>
           </div>
          </div>
        );
       }
```

Comment: Where are you calling `adminRegisterUser`?

Comment: @KarlGalvez after my render statement

Comment: @KarlGalvez
AdminRegister.propTypes = {
  adminRegisterUser: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  auth: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  errors: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};